# Wildfly Logging - How to prevent application log to be logged to serve.log

Tags: log4j, wildfly

I am trying to separate the logs by application. standalone.xml come with a pre-configured log for console and file. I created a file-handler for my application and the respective logger. But the logs are being logged in my application.log and the server.log.

I confirmed that my webapp does not contain the log4j.jar

***Can anyone let me know how to prevent the log4j to log for the server.log and only log to the respective application log file?***

Thank you very much!

-- Web application server: Wildfly 9.0.1

-- standalone.xml code

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:3.0">
<console-handler name="CONSOLE">
    <level name="INFO"/>
    <formatter>
        <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
    </formatter>
</console-handler>
<periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
    <formatter>
        <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
    </formatter>
    <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
    <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
    <append value="true"/>
</periodic-rotating-file-handler>

<periodic-rotating-file-handler name="SECVALFILE" autoflush="true">
    <formatter>
        <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
    </formatter>
    <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="securityvalidation.log"/>
    <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
    <append value="true"/>
</periodic-rotating-file-handler>

<logger category="com.arjuna">
    <level name="WARN"/>
</logger>
<logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
    <level name="WARN"/>
</logger>
<logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
    <level name="DEBUG"/>
</logger>
<logger category="sun.rmi">
    <level name="WARN"/>
</logger>
<logger category="jacorb">
    <level name="WARN"/>
</logger>
<logger category="jacorb.config">
    <level name="ERROR"/>
</logger>

<logger category="com.oracle.securityvalidation">
    <level name="DEBUG"/>
    <handlers>
        <handler name="SECVALFILE"/>
    </handlers>
</logger>
<root-logger>
    <level name="INFO"/>
    <handlers>
        <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
        <handler name="FILE"/>
    </handlers>
</root-logger>
```

......

Answer (score 2):

I already found the issue.

By default, the parent logger will process any message. we can use the logger attribute "**use-parent-handlers**" to specify if whether or not the message should be processed by the parent logger

Thank you so much anyway!

```
<logger category="com.oracle.securityvalidation" use-parent-handlers="false">
<level name="DEBUG"/>
<handlers>
    <handler name="SECVALFILE"/>
</handlers>
```

Comment: I'd advise using CLI or the web console over editing the raw XML. The CLI command to change the `use-parent-handlers` value would be; `/subsystem=logging/logger=com.oracle.securityvalidation:write-attribute(name=use-parent-handlers, value=false)`. The benefit of this is you won't need to shutdown or restart the server after executing the CLI command.

Comment: i did not knew this. Thank you so much.